# Wrong value in the Y axis

Tags: r, plot, axis

I am trying to analyze the EUR/USD time series as an example. In particular with monthly data. The problem is that in the Y axis the values ​​are not those reported in the historical series.

```
    eurusd <- read.table(“path/EURUSD.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE)
    head(eurusd)
      Date   Last        A       B      C     D
1 Gen 1999 1,1366   1,1742  1,1909 1,1338 -3,05%
2 Feb 1999 1,1025   1,1389  1,1397 1,0923 -3,00%
3 Mar 1999 1,0770   1,0987  1,1072 1,0683 -2,31%
4 Apr 1999 1,0570   1,0776  1,0888 1,0542 -1,86%
5 Mag 1999 1,0423   1,0589  1,0844 1,0393 -1,39%
6 Giu 1999 1,0357   1,0431  1,0563 1,0259 -0,63%
```

At this point, i save the values ​​of interest in a variable and create the historical series

```
x <- eurusd$Last
ts1 <- ts(x, start=c(1999, 1), end=c(2018, 12), freq=12)
```

When i try to plot `ts1`
[image: TS1]

As you can see, the Y axis reports wrong values. How can i fix it to show correct value of the "Last" column in the Y axis?

Comment: My guess is that `eurusd$Last` is in fact a `factor` (instead of a `numeric` vector), because of the `,` thousands separator. Try `x <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(eurusd$Last)))`

Comment: You are right! Thank you, I did not really think about it!

Comment: I changed the dataset itself, because i could re-download the file with the correct separator.